# How to further Interpret Variable Importance?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest

Forgive me if this is a duplicate question, I haven't found anything that answers my question specifically after searching for a while.

I have a dataset which I'm using to predict mobile app user retention, using the RandomForestClassifier in the SciKit Learn package. I'm pleased with the accuracy I'm getting and I'm planning on including a number of other metrics including precision, recall, Matthew's Corr Coefficient etc. I'm pretty sure the model is good.

The key thing that I'm interested in here are the features themselves. I want to know what is contributing to my user churn. I have extracted the feature importances and plotted a nice looking graph, but now I'm stuck. I'd ideally like to know *how* each variable influences the churned/not churned outcome. The problem with GINI feature importances is that I can see which ones are most influential, but for example with continuous variables I want to know at which value the RF found best to split on. I don't need to see this for every feature as I have 70+ only the most 'important' ones.

I saw a very nice decision tree plot [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10193/how-to-interpret-a-decision-tree-correctly), but cannot find any way of reproducing something similar using scikit learn. I'm open to other suggestions. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155128/plot-trees-for-a-random-forest-in-python-with-scikit-learn

Comment: It's also in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html). If your forest is big, you're probably better off with partial dependence plots instead of looking at every node in every tree.

Comment: @oW_ That's absolutely perfect! Just what I'm looking for! The doc even says it should be used with ideally 1 to 2 features selected from Variable Importance metrics. So this is an ideal next step.
If you'd write up an answer, I will happily mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation offers a couple options. To plot the individual trees in your forest, one can access them like `model.estimators_[n].tree_` and then plot them with `export_graphviz` as explained in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification), or you can follow [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html) that directly prints the structure in text format.

However, I would say this is not the best idea, because a feature can occur in different trees and nodes with different split points. You probably get a better intuition about your features from [partial dependence plots](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_partial_dependence.html) that try to isolate the effect of one variable on your response variable.

As a bonus, [here](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/ideas-on-interpreting-machine-learning?imm_mid=0ef03f&cmp=em-data-na-na-newsltr_20170320) is a good article about more alternatives to gain insight into your model (not all applicable to random forests).